# Change log - user permissions to view

Tags: permissions

Is there anyway to give users permission to the see the full change log without giving them administrator permissions? (they definitely cannot have these!)
We would like them see the details and see who made the change, in order that  they can fully curate the records across the team.

We are on Wordpress/Civi 4.6.12 (soon to be version 4.7.10)

Any help appreciated.

[image]

Comment: This does not appear to be so... Did anyone find a way 'round this? It doesn't seem right to have to give Access_CiviCRM just to enable users to view this info...

Answer (score 2):

By default the Report Contact Logging Report (Summary), that is used to display the detailed logging, requires the permission CiviCRM: administer CiviCRM.

[image]

You can change it to a permission that you feel comfortable with for your subset of users and save the report. Otherwise you need to create a new specific permission with an extension https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_permission/.